# Set projection from user input with Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system

This seems like to should be an easy thing to do, but I can't seem to make it work.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)  
output_working = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)  
PLSS_Intersected = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)  
spatial_ref = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)  

outCS = arcpy.SpatialReference("spatial_ref")  
outfc = os.path.join(output_working, "PLSS_Intersected")  
arcpy.Project_management(PLSS_Intersected, outfc, outCS)
```

EDIT:

How is the error massage that I receive. The very top is what prints out when I printed outCS.[image]

Comment: "spatial_ref" is a string, but spatial_ref is a variable holding a string.

Comment: One issue is you are providing the string `'spatial_ref'` to `arcpy.SpatialReference` rather than the value you have assigned to `spatial_ref` via `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)`

Comment: How do I correct this? Rather, how do I call the value instead of calling the variable holding the value?

Comment: `outCS = arcpy.SpatialReference(spatial_ref)`. This uses the variable, not a string that happens to be the variable name.

Comment: I think it will be worth using `print outCS` after you get that 4th parameter as text so that you (and we) can see what a test value is that you enter.

Comment: Ok, I tried running my script again, this time I printed the outCS. I edited the posted to include the resulting error message.

Comment: I'm not seeing the error message, but in any event, I think the [answer by @phloem](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/221323/115) may offer a better solution.

Comment: @phloem, do you have any advice on how to call the string, instead of the variable? I'm not familiar with how to do that.

Comment: From your edited question it looks like you are collecting the spatial reference as data type = spatial reference, which is fine. You then convert it to a string using GetParameterAsText(). Then you try to make a spatial reference out of a string that literally says "spatial_ref". Remove the quotes to have it read the value held in the variable. Or better yet, don't convert it to a string at all by using GetParameter() rather than GetParameterAsText() as I've answered below.

Comment: @sd1272, if this solved your problem, you can accept the answer [as explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the comments have identified the immediate problem (that you are using the string literal, "spatial_ref", rather than the variable, spatial_ref), you may find it easier to change the input parameter to data type = Spatial Reference, and use the spatial reference object itself, rather than converting the spatial reference to string and back to a spatial reference object.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)  
output_working = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)  
PLSS_Intersected = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)  
spatial_ref = arcpy.GetParameter(3)  # get spatial reference object

outfc = os.path.join(output_working, "PLSS_Intersected")  
arcpy.Project_management(PLSS_Intersected, outfc, spatial_ref) # set spatial reference to the object
```